# parse python datetime object in javascript within django app

Tags: javascript, python, django, datetime

I'm passing the following variable to a template:

```
from django.utils import timezone
dt = timezone.now()
print(type(dt))  # <class 'datetime.datetime'>
```

Everything works fine if I use it in my HTML directly:

```
{{ dt | date:'D d M Y' }}
```

which renders to `Thu 14 Dec 2017`.

However when I try to access the variable in my javascript I get an error:

```
<script>
  {{ dt | safe }}
</script>
```

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Furthermore, I get a slightly different error when I try to render a list of datetime objects:

```
dt_list = [timezone.now() for _ in range(3)]
```

and within my js:

```
<script>
  console.log({{ dt_list | safe }})
</script>
```

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

So my question is how can I convert a python datetime object to something I can use in JS?

Comment: Is your javascript in a separate `.js` file that is in static files or in the HTML page that is being rendered?

Comment: @StuartDines no it is not

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create a date object in JS.

```
<script>
    var dt = new Date("{{ dt.isoformat }}");
</script>
```